# Place a Chart on at a specific RadTabStrip Tab

Tags: asp.net, telerik, controls

What i'm trying to do is place a specific chart that is dynamically created on a specific tab.  For example Chart A will go to ColorTab and Chart B will go to HistoryTab

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="StripPanel" runat="server" Width="100%">
    <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="TabStrip" runat="server" MultiPageID="Monetary" SelectedIndex="0">
        <Tabs>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="MonetaryTab">
            </telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="VTab">
            </telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="ColorTab">
            </telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="HistoryTab">
            </telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="AdTab">
            </telerik:RadTab>
        </Tabs>
    </telerik:RadTabStrip>
</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
```

This is what i'm trying

```
Control masterC = FindControl("MonetaryTab");
                RadHtmlChart CarLotChart = ChartCreationClass.HTMLChartCreation();
                masterC.Controls.Add(CarLotChart);
```

It never finds the control to place the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recommendations from [this](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/tabstrip/dynamically-add-controls-to-radtabstrip.aspx) thread to accomplish this task:

```
RadHtmlChart CarLotChart = ChartCreationClass.HTMLChartCreation();
TabStrip.Tabs["MonetaryTab"].Controls.Add(CarLotChart);
```

Refer to the required Tab via any of the [following methods](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip-accessing-items-server-side.html).

Comment: Mikhail  I dont have .Items , what am I misisng?

Comment: Mikhail that actually changes the Tab itself into the Chart :)

Answer (score 0):

The RadTabStrip works in conjuction with RadmultiPage control. You first define the RafTabStrip and Tabs within it. Then have a RadMultiPage and define one page (type RadPageView) for each tab you have defined in TabStrip. The controls need to be added to the PageView and not to the tab directly.

I have created a small demo based on the TabStrip you have defined in the question.

Here is the TabStrip code:

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="TabStrip" runat="server" MultiPageID="Monetary" SelectedIndex="0" >
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="MonetaryTab">
                </telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="VTab">
                </telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="ColorTab">
                </telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="HistoryTab">
                </telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab Text="AdTab">
                </telerik:RadTab>
            </Tabs>
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>
```

Now here is the RadMultiPage definition:

```
<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="Monetary" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" OnLoad="Monetary_Load">
            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="monetaryTabPageView"/>
            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="vTabPageView"/>
            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="colorTabPageView"/>
            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="historyTabPageView"/>
            <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="adTabPageView"/>
        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

Notice that i am listening to OnLoad event of the RadMultiPage. In this demo - when the RadMultiPage loads, i will create charts and add it to eacg pageview we have. Here is the event handler code:

```
 protected void Monetary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddChart(monetaryTabPageView);
        AddChart(vTabPageView);
        AddChart(colorTabPageView);
        AddChart(historyTabPageView);
        AddChart(adTabPageView);
    }

    private void AddChart(RadPageView pageView)
    {
        RadHtmlChart chart = new RadHtmlChart();
        chart.ChartTitle.Text = pageView.ID + " chart";
        pageView.Controls.Add(chart);
    }
```

As you can see i just add the control directly to the pageview's controls collection.

NOTE: as a proof of concept i have created an empty chart i.e. a chart which has only title defined. you can go ahead and bind with some meaningful data if required.

here is the screenshot of how this looks:

[image: TabStrip demo]

Hope this answers your question.

Lohith (Tech Evangelist, Telerik India)